# "He wants everyone back" - Is the word back an adverb

Tags: adverbs, syntax

> He wants everyone back.

Is "back" an adverb? It doesn't modify the verb so has thrown me off a little.

Comment: But it does modify the verb!

Comment: Please edit the title so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> He wants everyone back.

*back* is an adjective functioning as an object complement.

*back* takes this definition in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back)

> back
> adjective [ not gradable ]
> US  /bæk/
> back adjective [not gradable] (RETURNED)

> having returned to a previous place or condition

This example is of the construction

> NP1 + V-tr + NP2 + ADJ

> The action verb is followed by a direct object.  The direct object is followed by an adjective functioning as an objective complement.

[Towson](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/SentPatt.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's an adverb, but it's modifying something that's implicit.

I would interpret the sentence as "He wants everyone *to come* back", or "He wants everyone *to be* back", or "He wants *to have* everyone back".

The exact meaning of the sentence would depend on its context.